# Can I Connect to dropbox api from localhost during development?

Tags: dropbox-api

I'm building a web application where I want to explore files on dropbox using their API. When I created the app on dropbox, I entered an url for the site. Now I can't figure out if it is possible while in development mode also to access dropbox from localhost or do I need to deploy first?

//Updated

The code from ASPNET with DropNET is like this

```
 private DropNetClient _dropboxClient = new DropNetClient("1234", "6789");

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Signup()
    {

        Session["DropNetUserLogin"] = _dropboxClient.GetToken();
        var url = _dropboxClient.GetTokenAndBuildUrl(Url.Action("Callback", null, null, Request.Url.Scheme));

        return Redirect(url);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public void Callback(string oauth_token)
    {
        var userlogin = Session["DropNetUserLogin"] as UserLogin;
        _dropboxClient.UserLogin = userlogin;


        Session["DropNetUserLogin"] = _dropboxClient.GetAccessToken();
        var accountinfo = _dropboxClient.AccountInfo();
    }
```

Keys are changed :)

Comment: What's the issue? (Are you getting an exception? Or never reaching your callback, or what?)

Comment: Commented on your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I just tried (and failed) to answer this on Twitter, but now I understand.

Yes, you can still make calls to the Dropbox API from anywhere and use localhost as your redirect URI for OAuth.

Comment: The issue is getting the accessToken. Please note that this is mostly samplecode from DropNet.

Comment: The actual error I get is Request token has not been properly authorized by a user. According to the dbx dedv information I'm a bit unsure if this could be a timing isue?

Comment: Accepted your answser as it is possible to connect from localhost, which was the opriginal question. Just as info sandbox mode should be used for any actions.

Comment: If we're talking about the same sandbox, sandbox mode should be used if and only if your app uses sandbox mode ("app folder permission"). As to the error with the request token, there shouldn't be a race condition there. Once the user has clicked "allow," it should be possible to exchange the request token for an access token.